# Slider blueprint template of a webpage

Tags: css, html, templates, slider

Im looking for a single-page template with a slider like here  : http://www.squarespace.com/about/

I was searching for sliders and similar things and found 2 main categories: image sliders and full-page sliders, but nothing like in that webpage. Home someone know good template for this.

I can modify things a little but my javascript skills are too low to make such clear and smooth thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe this might be of help to you

https://github.com/JoeBonham/jQuery-Full-Width-Image-Slider

Comment: Well, it doesn't slide nav buttons. I think its the main feature in the squarespace's slider